equivalence of grading by integers and a $\mathbb{C}^*$ action on a vector space
I'm currently reading this paper and I have a problem with the statement at the end of page 2.
it says that a $\mathbb{C}^*$ action on a vector space $V$ is equivalent to a grading of $V$ by the group of integers.
my questiojn is why are these equivalent? (knowing the grading we can clearly give the action)
My basic idea is that the homogeneous parts are supposed to be $V_k=\{v \in V | c.v= c^kv\}$ I can't seem to show that $V= \bigoplus V_k$ and I don't get why we are using the integers specifically, I do  have an idea about $z^r$ not being well defined for non-integer $r$ but couldn't go any further.
I have seen a similar theorem for Rings which are finitly generated commutative $\mathbb{C}^*$ algebras but again I couldn't prove it.
I tried to say if $R_k$ are empty then so is $R$ (using quotients this is equivalent to the theorem)
I would appreciate any hint or solution about these 2 theorems.

The article is slightly incorrect (or rather, I should say imprecise). What is true is that an action of the algebraic group $\mathbb{G}_m$ yields a grading. An arbitrary action of the abstract group $\mathbb{C}^*$ has no reason to give a nice $\mathbb{Z}$-grading (unless I'm mistaken and something miraculous is going on).

The action of the algebraic group is on a vector space?

Yes, in the sense of a representation of the group, so a morphism of algebraic groups $\mathbb{G}_m\to GL(V)$ for some vector space $V$.
